# Error: All configured authentication methods failed levels: 'client-authentication'

Tags: node.js, ssh

I am using node.js ssh2 module.I have installed ssh2 module by executing the command 'npm install ssh2'.However, when I use ssh2 to connect to a remote server, it always output the error:
[Error: All configured authentication methods failed] levels: 'client-authentication'

This is my code

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client
var conn = new Client();
var option = {
    host: '10.171.65.154',
    port: 22,
    username: 'root',
    password: '123456'
};

conn.on('ready', function(){
    console.log('Client :: ready');
    conn.sftp(function(err, sftp){
        if(err) throw err;
        sftp.readdir('home', function(err, list){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.dir(list);
            conn.end();
        });
    });
}).on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
}).connect(option);
```

However, I can not connect successfully.I am sure the username and password are correct and I can connect successfully by SecureCRT.

it always output the error:
[Error: All configured authentication methods failed] levels: 'client-authentication'

Comment: Perhaps your server doesn't support password auth, but instead uses `keyboard-interactive` to "enforce" typing in a password manually. Set `tryKeyboard: true` in your config object and listen for the `keyboard-interactive` event (see the ssh2 docs for information on how to correctly handle this event).

Comment: My server supports password authentication.If I use jsch and the same config in my Java code, it can connect successfully.

Comment: I think jsch will try to automatically handle `keyboard-interactive`-based password authentication by searching for a 'Password:' interactive prompt. Try what I suggested. The password auth mechanism and `keyboard-interactive` mechanism with a 'Password:' prompt in ssh are two different things.

Comment: I just try to handle keyboard-interactive event.However, I do not know the usage.I tryed like this:`conn.on('keyboard-interactive', {prompt: 'Password: ', echo: true}, function(){
 console.log('yyy here');
});`Then it throws TypeError:listener must be a function.   How should I do?

Comment: It's an event, so you have to add a function for the event handler, not an object. The values passed to the event handler function are documented [here](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2#client-events).

Comment: Could you give me an example? I have study the document.However, I really do not know how to use it.

Comment: You add an event handler like: `conn.on('keyboard-interactive', function(name, instructions, lang, prompts, finish) { /* "read" prompts and pass array of responses to finish() */ })`

Comment: Thank you so much.I know little about ssh2 authentication.And I really do not know how to handle keyboard-interactive.I have much to learn and will try later.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have to handle keyboard-interactive authentication (which is not the same as password). Try something like this:

```
connection.on('ready', function(){
    console.log("Connected!");
}).on('error', function(err){
    console.error(err);
}).on('keyboard-interactive', function (name, descr, lang, prompts, finish) {
    // For illustration purposes only! It's not safe to do this!
    // You can read it from process.stdin or whatever else...
    var password = "your_password_here";
    return finish([password]);

    // And remember, server may trigger this event multiple times
    // and for different purposes (not only auth)
}).connect({
    host: "your.host.or.ip",
    port: 22,
    username: "your_login",
    tryKeyboard: true
});
```